# jQuery mouse scroll script speed will not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

had a google....

Tried changing my website scroll settings & nothing is happening.

Anyone have a write up or table on mouse scroll jQuery scripts and functions?

(Caches were cleared, cross browser test etc.)

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){  

    if(checkBrowser() == 'Google Chrome' && device.windows()){

        if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);

            window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;



            var time = 330;

            var distance = 300;


            function wheel(event) {

                if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 90;

                else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

                handle();

                if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

                event.returnValue = false;

            }



            function handle() {

                jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({

                    scrollTop: jQuery(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)

                }, time);

            }

    }

});

function checkBrowser(){

    var ua = navigator.userAgent;



    if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return 'Internet Explorer';

    if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > 0) return 'Firefox';

    if (ua.search(/Opera/) > 0) return 'Opera';

    if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > 0) return 'Google Chrome';

    if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return 'Safari';

    if (ua.search(/Konqueror/) > 0) return 'Konqueror';

    if (ua.search(/Iceweasel/) > 0) return 'Debian Iceweasel';

    if (ua.search(/SeaMonkey/) > 0) return 'SeaMonkey';

    if (ua.search(/Gecko/) > 0) return 'Gecko';

    return 'Search Bot';

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The script looks a bit outdated. The `.load()` function isn't used like that anymore and browser sniffing is deprecated as well. An approach with the mousewheel plugin (a real gem) would be more reliable and future proof. Here's a script that uses it, making the function itself quite compact :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpPdmX?editors=001

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {

  var time = 330;
  var distance = 300;

  jQuery(this).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({

      scrollTop: jQuery(window).scrollTop()-(distance*delta)

    }, time);

  return false;
  });
});

// mousewheel.js can be placed here, outside of function scope
```

It needs a bit of extra script with that plugin but it is well worth it. There also is a `wheel` event but unfortunately this is still not supported by Opera. In any case, more code would be needed to normalise the delta of the mousewheel turns (this is where mousewheel.js is at it's best).

I'm guessing the `$` character is reserved on the web page but if not, the `jQuery` references could be replaced with it. By the way - you might want to check which version of jQuery is linked to on the site... if there are any other scripts depending on deprecated features (not that there are too many), some things might stop functioning correctly when it is updated. The `.on` method was introduced in version 1.8 - if you'd like to stick with an older version the above script would need a minor rewrite.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and although it works on your example. It doesn't work on my site! Nothing changes when i replaced my smoothscroll js file with your code.... Strange?

Comment: Just to check the obvious first - did you include the script at the bottom of the Codepen example? If you did, the issue is probably caused by the use of the `.on()` method not being compatible with the version of jQuery that is linked to on the site. For the quickest check you could try to replace the first line with `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`. I reckon the page doesn't need to be fully loaded for the user to be able to scroll anyway (so if it works, no need to change it back).

Comment: I just replaced my script for yours above to test and changed difference to 900, included jQuery(document).ready(function() { and no difference.

Comment: The code above uses a plugin though (mousewheel.js) that is pasted in the script on Codepen and only mentioned at the bottom here. So it's best to copy from live example (don't forget the `jQuery(document).ready ...` of course). If you already took it from there, maybe you could post a link so I can do some troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

add this function in you script tag

and add data-scroll-speed="10" in your body tag. you can adjust the scroller speed of body

```
$(function () {
            var boxes = $('[data-scroll-speed]'),
        $window = $(window);
            $window.on('scroll', function () {
                var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
                boxes.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
          scrollspeed = parseInt($this.data('scroll-speed')),
          val = -(scrollTop / scrollspeed);
                    $this.css('transform', 'translateY(' + val + 'px)');
                });
            });
        })
```

example: fiddled [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/nobot7cn/2/)

check weather this is what you wanted